# Can anyone tell me how to hide the contents of a text box

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down button named bank. 
I have 3 text boxes named t1, t2 and t3
if i am not selecting any of the banks all the three text boxes should be enabled..

am getting it..
but my problem is..

first i have selected any one from the drop down button, and after some time i have changed it to choose bank(i.e; the 0th index).. but even then the data in text boxes are still there itself.. how to hide it..

Comment: Please provide some code and an example.

Comment: You can't hide the contents of the textbox. You can hide the textbox itself or set it to empty. You can also disable it or make it read only.

Comment: i mean a select..there are three values in the select.. one is choose type, 2nd one is x and third one is y... i do have three text boxes also named t1, t2 and t3... i will be able to enter into the text boxes only if i select among x or y... i have selected x and have inputted some value to t1.. again i am going back to the select.. ie; am selecting the first one ie; choose type, at this time i need to clear the contents in the text boxes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot hide the data, you can clear the data from the textbox before disabling using following script

```
document.getElementById("yourTextBoxID").value = "";
```

Comment: Only problem with this is that the data is lost, should the boxes need to be re-enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "hide" the text in a text box. You either disable the textbox, clear the textbox's text, or hide the darn thing. In your case I would add 3 blank textboxes that are invisible. when you select `bank` hide the real textboxes and show the three 'fake' textboxes that are blank and disabled/locked.

My Javascript syntax is horrible, so [here is a jQuery Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/p6KZG/).

Comment: Thanks. If this is your accepted solution, you should click the checkmark next to it so future readers know.

Answer (score 0):

Before you hide the textbox, you have a couple of options:

- You could copy the contents of the textbox into a Javascript variable so you can repopulate the box later if you need to, or
- You could hide the textbox and replace it with a new textbox that is empty

Comment: or store the value in some hidden html field

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the textboxes before selecting drop down item.You can write this clear stmts in drop down change event.